# how to get request param in express

Tags: express, routes

This my code:

```
router.all('/trips:key?', (req, res) => {
console.log("Yeah")
console.log(req.params.key)
```

})

> GET http:localhost:8080/trips?keyword=kong

Output :

```
Yeah 
undefined
```

How to get value `kong` in `keyword`

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope this will work for `GET http:localhost:8080/trips?keyword=kong`

your route should be `/trips` not `/trips:key?`

```js
 router.all('/trips', (req, res) => {
    console.log("Yeah")
    console.log(req.query.keyword)
    
    })
```